# Can I add text to a form file upload field?

Tags: 7, forms

Is it possible to add text/markup to a file upload field similar to the image below?

[image: file field with text]

I thought that something like

```
$form['actions']['edit-field-upload']['#prefix'] = 'First';
```

in a hook_form_alter would work, but don't see anything.

Comment: I think you will need to override `theme_file` theme function with your own one and set the `#theme` in the FAPI definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a #prefix to a file upload field using hook_form_alter, but I don't think it will give you what you're looking for

```
function test_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'test_node_form') {  //custom content type of 'test'
    //custom field in the content type called 'field_test_upload'
    $form['field_test_upload']['#prefix'] = '<p>test prefix</p>';
  }
}
```

With the above code I have a custom content type of "test" and a custom field called "field_test_upload"

When adding a #prefix to the field I get the following results:

[image]